# how to determine whether number is even or odd using each function?

Tags: c, algorithm

```
typedef int bool;

bool even(int n)
{
  return odd(n-1);
}

bool odd(int n)
{
  return even(n-1);
}
```

I am having difficulty understanding this code in C
 1.Please explain why this definition is wrong.
 2.correct this code and make even and odd call each other.

Thank you!

Comment: what is the smallest odd number?

Comment: This code obviously falls into an infinite loop.

Comment: search for `base condition in recursion`.

Comment: I could (sorta) understand having `even` call `odd` OR the other way around, but having them both call each other recursively with a base case (probably zero) is going to be horribly inefficient.

Answer (score 4):

If you manually trace this code, you will quickly see that the functions will call each other an infinite number of times. They will never return.  They will just keep calling each other forever.

This will surely lead to a "Stack Overflow".  Which is the error that this site gets its name from!

Comment: please see base condition in order to prevent infinite looping

Answer (score 1):

As you know these two functions call each other recursively, but there is no condition to stop the calling each other and it goes infinitely. Hence you can modify your code likes the following:

```
typedef int bool;

bool even(int n)
{
  if(n == 0)
       return 1;
  if(n == 1)
       return 0;
  return odd(n-1);
}

bool odd(int n)
{
  if(n == 1)
      return 1;
  if(n == 0)
      return 0;
  return even(n-1);
}
```

For example follow `odd(2)`. Their call each other likes the following:

```
odd(2) -> even(1) -> return 0
```

Or `odd(7)`:

```
odd(7) -> even(6) -> odd(5) -> even(4) -> odd(3) -> even(2) -> odd(1) -> return 1
```

Hence if passing an odd number to the `odd` function, these recursive calling finished by 1 on `odd` function and the same for `even` function and vice versa for passing odd or even number to `even` and `odd` respectively.

Comment: `odd(-1)` might loop a long time.

Answer (score 0):

> 2.correct this code and make even and odd call each other.

To answer just #2

```
// Better to use standard types and includes. 
// typedef int bool;
#include <stdbool.h>

// declare before use
bool odd(int n);

// At most 2 recursive calls.    
bool even(int n) {
  // return odd(n-1);
  return (n < -1 || n > 1) ? !odd(n) : n==0;
}

bool odd(int n) {
  // return even(n-1);
  return !even(n%2);
}
```

---

For those concerned about high probability, `n & 1` fails as an `odd()` test with the wrong answer for negative values on [1's complement machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement) rusting away in the big-iron heaven

Answer (score -1):

the code snippet

```
bool even(int n) {
  return odd(n-1);
}
```

And

```
bool odd(int n) {
  return even(n-1);
}
```

your calling `even()` & `odd()` recursively and there is no terminating condition which results in stack overflow.

to check whether given number is `even` or `odd`, you have to check `0th` bit status, if `0th` bit is `zero` means its `even` number, if `0th` bit is `one(1)` means its `odd` number at one stage.

Instead of this you can use bitwise logic if at all recursion is not compulsory.

```
bool even(int n) {
        return n & 1; /*bitwise And, in all odd number 0th bit is set(1) */
}
```

Or if you want to do using recursion then put the base condition. for e.g

```
typedef int bool;
bool even_odd_method(int n) {
        if(n<2) {
                return n%2;
        }
        return even_odd_method(n-2);
}
int main(void) {
        int number;
        printf("\n enter the number \n");
        scanf("%d",&number);
        number = number > 0 ? number : -number;/*if input no is negative */
        int ret1 = even_odd_method(number);

        if(ret1 == 0) {
                printf("even \n");
        }
        else {
                printf("odd  \n");
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, `even_odd_method(-1)` returns -1, yet does print `"odd  \n"`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that.  I forget to put condition for negative number.

Answer (score -1):

```
bool isOdd( int num )
{
    return( num & 1 );
}

bool isEven( int num )
{
    return( !(num & 1) );
}
```

Comment: OP has two questions: *1.Please explain why this definition is wrong. 2.correct this code and make even and odd call each other.*  This answers neither.

Comment: the OPs question: *how to determine whether number is even or odd using each function?*  The two functions I posted in my answer are the easiest way to perform that calculation.  The nonsense posted by the OP is definitely not the way to accomplish the desired functionality.  There is nothing in the question about how to make the two current functions work and having the two functions call each other is a (very) bad idea.

Comment: the OP further asks: * am having difficulty understanding this code in C 1.Please explain why this definition is wrong. 2.correct this code and make even and odd call each other.*  1)  explaining the OPs posted code, makes the assumption that it works, however; it does not work, so I'm not going to waste the OPs time.  2) how to make it work? The answer to that is the two functions I posted.